# Replace keyboard with custom functionality

Tags: keyboard, midi

I'm looking for a way to intercept key presses from a certain keyboard (so not general keyboard input) and prevent Windows and other apps from receiving any key presses from this keyboard, essentially creating a macro keyboard.

I'm trying to create an app which would mask the keyboard as a MIDI device to help me with controlling my DAW.

I have an Arduino if this is impossible to do with software only.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to grab specific keys by calling [RegisterHotKey()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey) or by installing a global [keyboard hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644984(v=vs.85)) or [low-level keyboard hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644985(v=vs.85)). However, these functions do not allow to differentiate the source device of the key.

To prevent Windows from treating that keyboard as a general keyboard, you would have to write and install your own kernel driver.

If your Arduino can act as a USB device, you can make it a USB MIDI device that simply sends the desired MIDI messages.